# Google Cloud Services not giving me permission to view a bucket I've just created?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am an organisation of one person, just me.  I've been using GCS with no problem for a few years.  Today I've created a new bucket, and am currently using `gsutil` to populate it, with no obvious problems.

In the GCS web app I've just tried to click into the bucket via the Storage browser, just to verify it was being populated, and was told

`Additional permissions required to list objects in this bucket: Ask a project or bucket owner to grant you 'storage.buckets.list' permissions (e.g. by giving your account the IAM Storage Object Viewer role).`

Ok... but I created it?   Whatever, I'll click on the menu button (three vertical dots) next to the bucket name and select `Edit bucket permissions`.

`You do not have permission to view the permissions of the selected resource`

Right...

Any ideas?!

Comment: I've managed to fix this, by adding a role of `Storage > Storage Admin` to myself.  Seems a bit odd that I need to do that when I already have the role `Owner`, which underneath it states `Full access to all resources`.  I'm guessing it's a GDPR thing, and that the "Full access to all resources" text is outdated and needs correcting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You figured it out based on your comments. To reduce future guesswork, a [really good reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) exists for figuring out what roles get which permissions.